# How do I delete a project in IntelliJ IDEA 9?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I've just created a new project but the structure is incorrect so I'd like to start again. It is it possible to delete a project from within IntelliJ or do I just have to close it and delete the relevant .iml/.idea files?

Comment: In this particular instance I have created a new project in the same dir and it has overwritten the old one, so not really a problem. Would still be nice to know if it's possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way would be to close IDEA and delete the project directory or just create a new project in the different directory.

Answer (score 2):

There was no context menu on the project for me. Instead, try this:

1. File > Close Project
2. In the project selection dialog, select your project
3. Press the *delete* key on your keyboard

Comment: This is the correct way. It removes the project from Intellij without deleting the code on disk.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can select file -> Open Project. and then by right clicking delete project

Comment: your suggestion is for eclipse,but he is asking about IDEA.