# Is there a way to cleanly delete projects in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am aware that you can remove a recent project by selecting the project in the startup window and hitting delete, but many files associated with that project remain.

When a new project under the same name as the removed project is created, some files from the previous project show up.

Is there a way to remove the entire project other than deleting the project directory via commandline?

Comment: I know that Eclipse stores project data in the workspace directory. Maybe you can find the project metadata and delete it in your IntelliJ workspace folder. The project's ".idea" folder should be removed.

Comment: Refer this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372010/how-do-i-delete-a-project-in-intellij-idea-9

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe there is a misunderstanding here, since when I select a project in the startup window (IntelliJ v14) and hit *delete*, it prompts me:

[image]

This tells me that you are not actually deleting the project, you are just deleting it from the recent projects list.

I suggest you close the project and delete the project folder from your file system manually to be sure the delete is done fully and cleanly.